# Checking the existence of a certain array

Tags: java, arrays

What is the best way to check the existence of a certain array name? for example, if i had a array called:

```
String array1[] = new String[]{"abc", "def", "ghi"};
```

what is the best way to check if `array1` exists or not?

Additionally, is there a way to see if the string `"abc"` exists inside the array if we don't know which index `"abc"` is in?

EDIT: I'm planning to have the user input a string and check if the input string matches with any of the string array variable names

Comment: If you declare `array1`, then it exists

Comment: In which situation will you use this?

Comment: You probably meant: `String[] array1 =...`

Comment: `if(Arrays.asList(array1).contains("abc"))`

Comment: You really should learn about _objects_, _references_, and _variables_. I suggest you work through [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), starting with the trails covering the basics. Once read, you realize that _objects don't have a name_. A variable is just a reference to an existing object. Furthermore: The existence of a variable and the excistence of an object are independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check whether the array exists you could use

```
if(array != null){
//some code for when the array exists
} else {
//some other code for when the array does not exist.
}
```

If you want to check, whether an array has more than 0 entries, please edit your question.

For checking if the string "abc" is part of the array, you can use

```
if(Arrays.asList(array1).contains("abc")){...}
```

To learn more about arrays, you should read the documentation for arrays:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html